# openstack : Deleted a project/tenant my mistake. How to restore it without rolling back the controller DB backup

Tags: database, project, openstack, openstack-keystone

I had deleted the admin project because of which non of the openstack command works. I am able to restore the problem by rolling back the controller DB backup. The DB backup requires various steps and it takes time.

In some of the posts it is mention to use admin_token in keystone.conf and export the necessary environment to enable openstack command and create the project/tenant.

Instead I wanted to insert the the project and user related information directly to the DB to fix the issue in keystone databases. But not sure the list of required tables I need to work on?

Comment: Why do you want to insert things into the DB if you can also restore the admin user and project using the 'admin_token'? I think the latter option would be safer.

Comment: I agree with @BakaKuna. Furthermore, the database structure may vary from release to release. To know the list of required tables, you need to consult the source of your OpenStack release.

Comment: I tried to use admin_token method. But i had error running the openstack command. I had a timeline to complete the task so i  restore the controller DB to fixed the issue.  Just to learning purpose i wanted to know the regarding the necessary tables.